# What is using my CD/DVD drive

Tags: windows-8.1, optical-media

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop and the CD/DVD drive periodically makes noises as if something is trying to acccess it, even though there is no disk in there. Also the optical disk access mouse cursor periodically appears.

Is there any way to diagnose this?